# Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, generics

I'm fairly new to generics so I wonder if somebody can explain the following problem I'm having. In virtually all my controllers in an ASP.NET MVC application I need to return a filtered list (to populate a JqGrid as it happens where the user will have specified certain filtering criteria). Each controllers list method will return a different IQueryable list so I set about creating a generic method to handle this.

While I was creating my method I defined it in a specific controller. Everything compiled and I got the results I expected. Because I want to call this method from all my controllers I assumed I could simply create another static class, put the method in there and then call that method from all my controllers. But if I try to move the method to anywhere else other than the controller thats calling it, the compiler complains about the last line of the method with the following error:

*The type arguments for method `System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)` 
cannot be inferred from the usage. 
Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilteredList<T>(IQueryable<T> list, string filters)
{
     var qb = new QueryBuilder<T>();
     var whereClause = qb.BuildWhereClause(filters);
     return list.Where(whereClause);
}
```

I've tried `list<T>.Where(whereClause)` and `list.Where<T>(whereClause)` and just about every other combination, can anyone explain to me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: what does qb.BuildWhereClause return? Expression<Func<T,bool>>?

Comment: You'd think `Where<T>` should work.

Comment: When you use `Where<T>(T)`, what error message are you getting (it should be different)? Also, what is the precise actual type of `whereClause`?

Comment: IQueryable<T>.Where accepts an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` as defined in Queryable or `Func<TSource, bool>` as defined in Enumerable.
Can you indicate what the return type is for `qb.BuildWhereClause(filters);`

Comment: It actually returns a string, I'm using Dynamic Linq - but your answer set me on the right path, it was basically missing the reference and using statements to dynamic linq. All working correctly now - thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 8):

That would suggest that your `BuildWhereClause` method isn't returning the appropriate type.

The compiler is trying to infer the type of `TSource` from both `list` and `whereClause`. Now `whereClause` *should* be an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but I suspect it's not. Hover over the `var` in the declaration of `whereClause` to find out what it actually is. I wouldn't recommend using `var` when the return type isn't obvious.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your reply, as you can see from my other post BuildWhereClause is actually returning a string because I'm using Dynamic Linq - all working correctly now. Good point about not using var for non obvious return types, I'll try to be more explicit in the future. P.S. Loving your c# in depth book by the way.